# Transparent button in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to make my button transparent. im Doing opacity 0 but it doest not worked for me. How I Can Make My Button Transparent in normal and pressed state.

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="140"  Height="80" Margin="0,240,0,0" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/Search.png"/>
                </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to use the Search.png image as your button?

If you are, why not hook into the MouseLeftButtonDown event to perform a particular action.

I am not sure what you are gaining by wanting to replace the whole of the button control with an image and then making the button itself transparent.

Comment: The better way to do it would be to use Blend to create a custom button.  That way you keep all of the functionality of a button, and don't have accidental clicks due to the image's MouseLeftButtonDown event firing when the user intended something else, a swipe, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting all of the functionality of a button but want it to look like an image, you should look into using Expression Blend to make your button look the way you want.

Here is a walkthrough of how to do it.  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cd80b9/creating-a-custom-button-from-an-image-in-expression-blend/